# UITabBar item hiding error

Tags: ios, uitabbaritem

Giving error when trying to hide tab bar item

> -[UITabBarItem setHidden:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>
> 0   CoreFoundation                      0x0493cdf6
>   **exceptionPreprocess + 182   1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x03fe4837 objc_exception_throw + 44    2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x04944a75 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 277  3
>
>   CoreFoundation                      0x0488d9c7 ___forwarding_** + 1047
>     4   CoreFoundation                      0x0488d58e
>   _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14    5   SkyDroid-Pro                        0x00116037 -[tabBarAppAppDelegate
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 279     6   UIKit
>   0x00a8c47c -[UIApplication
>   _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 291  7   UIKit                               0x00a8d187 -[UIApplication
>   _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2869   8   UIKit                               0x00a906df -[UIApplication
>   _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1639   9   UIKit                               0x00aa9410 **84-[UIApplication
>   _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke
>   + 59  10  UIKit                               0x00a8f2eb -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 155   11  FrontBoardServices                  0x0525ffee __37-[FBSWorkspace
>   clientEndTransaction:]_block_invoke_2 + 71    12  FrontBoardServices
>
>   0x0525fc34 __40-[FBSWorkspace _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke +
>   54    13  FrontBoardServices                  0x05271775
>   __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 26     14  CoreFoundation                      0x048607a0
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 16  15  CoreFoundation                      0x048560b3 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 195    16  CoreFoundation
>   0x04855f0b __CFRunLoopRun + 2715  17  CoreFoundation
>   0x048551ab CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443     18  CoreFoundation
>   0x04854fdb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123   19  UIKit
>   0x00a8ecb0 -[UIApplication _run] + 571    20  UIKit
>   0x00a92386 UIApplicationMain + 1526   21  SkyDroid-Pro
>   0x00115efc main + 76  22  libdyld.dylib
>   0x04320ac9 start + 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `hidden` property is present on `UIView` and its subclasses. `UITabBarItem` is not a subclass of `UIView`. It's a subclass of `UIBarItem`, which inherits from `NSObject`.

Trying to call the selector `setHidden:` on an instance of `UITabBarItem` will cause it to crash, given it doesn't have a method to handle that.